# tmux bind a key to redraw buffer

Tags: tmux

Many terminal programs these days such as PuTTY have a scroll bar which you can scroll up and see lines that scrolled off the screen.  Tmux has an internal notion of a scrollback buffer for each window as well.

Sometimes I need to refresh the lines in my local scroll buffer with what’s in tmux’s.  For example, if I need to copy-paste something which is larger than the actual screen size and I’ve just reattached and my local scroll buffer is empty, or if I’ve changed windows a few times and disturbed the scroll buffer.

tmux has a capture-pane (capturep) command which can output its scrollback buffer.  I can get the output of the buffer in a file.  I can manually cat that file out to the screen if I'm at a shell prompt.

What I'd really like to do is bind this to a key
effectively repainting the screen and the lines which scrolled off of it.

Here's what I tried:

```
bind-key -T prefix C-l capturep -e -J -p -S- -E-
```

Unfortunately, when I press the prefix key followed by ctrl-L, all I see is the message "Can't write to client" briefly at the bottom of the screen.

I've tried adding -t0 to target window 0 which is the current window but no matter what target I specify I always get the same message.

If I run it in the shell as `tmux capturep -e -J -p -S- -E-` it does output correctly, but I really need it bound to a tmux key because I may not be at the shell prompt when I need to look back in the scrollback buffer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I've done it:

```
bind-key C-l "capturep -eJ -S- -E- -b tmp; save-buffer -b tmp ~/.tmux.capture; delete-buffer -b tmp; run-shell \"head -c -1 ~/.tmux.capture > #{pane_tty}\""
```

Explanation:

bind  ctrl-L to:

1. capture the entire current window including text decorations and whitespace and store in buffer 'tmp'
2. save buffer tmp to the file ~/.tmux.capture
3. delete buffer tmp
4. run a shell command 'head -c -1' to send the .tmux.capture file directly to the pane's tty.  head -c -1 removes trailing newline from the file so the cursor hopefully lines up with the prompt.

Caveats:

This works if you have a single window in a pane, not going to look pretty if you have tiled your windows.  Not going to work well if you're in the editor like vi or emacs.

This is most useful to look back at the output of the shell using your local scroll buffer, e.g. PuTTY.